# How to call a apex rest service from salesforce mobile sdk-android?

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, rest-service

I need to call apex rest service from salesforce mobile sdk-android. I can execute the soql query by calling `RestRequest.getRequestForQuery()` method. How to call apex service from RestRequest class?

Comment: I am stuck with the same thing. Here  I am talking about Native code and not `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me. I created an apex rest service and called the service from index.html using force.js

```
var fetchRecords = function (successHandler) {

    force.apexrest('/services/apexrest/MyRestService', successHandler, function(error) {
        alert('Failed to fetch data: ' + error);
    });
};
```

And this is how the function was called

```
fetchRecords(function(data) {
         console.log(data);

    })
}
```

Comment: I think OP has asked about the Native `java/kotlin` API from SDK to do so.